# How do I serve ALL images using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to learn how to serve all images using Node.js without using a framework like Express. I will eventually use Express but I want to learn how things work.

This question has been answered before with this solution:

```
fs = require('fs');
http = require('http');
url = require('url');


http.createServer(function(req, res){
var request = url.parse(req.url, true);
var action = request.pathname;

if (action == '/logo.gif') {
 var img = fs.readFileSync('./logo.gif');
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif' });
 res.end(img, 'binary');
 } else { 
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
 res.end('Hello World \n');
 }
 }).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

This solution seems to only handle one image and I dont want to have to write code for every single image I have. Is there a better solution?

***How can I serve all images within a folder?***

I was thinking is there a way to check the extension of a request like? For example if the end of the request has .png then check the images folder and use the correct content type image/png?

Comment: Here is a good starting point: https://gist.github.com/hectorcorrea/2573391 It handles most common file formats.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is:

```
if (/.gif$/i.test(action)) {
  var img = fs.readFileSync(action);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif' });
  res.end(img, 'binary');
}
```

Though I would highly recommend using and/or learning the source code of [connect.static](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) middleware. This is what Express uses itself.